# Can not run app with weceem plugin

Tags: grails, weceem

Hello I'm trying to use weceem plugin but i got error:
Message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.Set
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.Set
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.Set
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.Set
->>   45 | buildSessionFactory .............................
```

Every i've configured the plugin like it said on doc: http://jcatalog.github.io/weceem-plugin/guide/2.ConfigurationAndInstallation.html
and i also run the weceemapp demo from :https://github.com/julyantonicheva/weceem-app and it were working well. 
So idon't see the unmapped reference class like it says may someone has ever mett this error.

A little precision before plugin the application were running well
Grails 2.4.4
Windows 7
Builconfig (for conflict on plugin eventually)

```
plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
      //  runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.19"//for  multi tenant
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        //new
        compile ":i18n-templates:1.1.0.1"
        compile ":ckeditor:4.4.1.0"
        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
        //security
        compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"
        compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:1.0-RC3"
        compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:1.0.7"

        //multi societe0.9.0-SNAPSHOT"
        compile "org.grails.plugins:multi-tenant-single-db:0.8.3"
        //excel import
        compile ":excel-import:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
        //audit log
        compile "org.grails.plugins:audit-logging:1.1.1"
        //test weceem
        compile ':weceem:1.4.1'
        compile ":weceem-spring-security:1.4"
    }
```

Tks regards

Comment: Weceem is outdated, if you are doing a new application i will advice not to use it

Comment: Hello it's for a new application, i'm interesting to create web portal for hr information in my companie. Is there something better for what i want that you can advised me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly i find the solution.
In fact by updating my user class adding autorities field for weceem.springsecurity.details.mapper it created 2 autorities field one from my class and one from plugin.
I change for my class and put rautorities instead of autorities now it's solved app is running.
tks for viewers

Comment: You are shooting your self in foot by using weeceem, the plugin is dead, no one is maintaining it, dont use it, unless you want to maintain the plugin your self.

Comment: Ok that true i'll give up if i can't make thinks evolve so
Any idea about web portal